# Magic of UpdateAll

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I wrote the code below in cakephp for and updateAll query like

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->updateAll(array('stauts'=>'active'),array());
```

The above code's equivalent `SQL` query is generated like this

```
UPDATE User SET status='active' WHERE 0 = 1;
```

When I write updateAll in cakephp like below

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->updateAll(array('stauts'=>'active'));
```

This code's equivalent `SQL` query is generated like this

```
UPDATE User SET status='active';
```

I don't know why this happens.

If you do not understand my question let me know in comments, I'll explain in shortly.

Comment: Being at developer side, we should follow the conversion made by the cakephp,second part of updateAll function contains the conditions,we shouldn't pass the condition if we don't have any...

Comment: Better to ask cakePhp creator might be they have missed to consider this situation.

Comment: How can I ask cakePhp creator team?

Comment: you can post issues here https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues and  they having other communities too .check their official site http://cakephp.org/

Comment: @RajeevRanjan this isn't a bug - creating issues are for **problems** not questions.

Comment: @AD7six Of course it  isn't a bug.I think it could be consider as enhancement .so that `$this->User->updateAll(array('stauts'=>'active'),array());` and `$this->User->updateAll(array('stauts'=>'active'));` generate same sql query.

Comment: @AD7six I already studies your answer,Let if I want to update on conditions and if no condition there just update all records without conditions.the below code will work partially in this situation.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan I don't understand you point/question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### It's a safety catch

Conditions are often dynamic based on user input. Consider a controller action like so:

```
function enableAll() {
    $conditions = array();

    ...

    if (whatever) {
        // Update only today's records
        $conditions['created > '] = $yesterday;
    }

    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        // Update only my records
        $conditions['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    }

    $this->Widget->updateAll(
        array('active' => 1),
        $conditions
    );
}
```

Logically conditions can be one of two things:

- An array matching some or no records
- An empty array

When it's an empty array, did the developer mean to update all records, or *no* records?

CakePHP can't know for sure, but if passed, an empty conditions array is more likely to be an error where the intention was to update nothing. Therefore to protect developers from accidentally updating everything, a condition is used which won't match any records (`WHERE 0 = 1` is false - it will match no rows, always.).

That's why this:

```
// I definitely want to update the whole table
$model->updateAll($update);
```

is treated differently than this:

```
// mistake? maybe the conditions have been forgotten...
$model->updateAll($update, array());
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan I'm not sure what you are asking that isn't addressed in the answer.

Comment: With find query if condition is empty array then select all records and In updateAll if condition is empty array then why not updated all records?

Comment: @AD7six Very good to know that this case is already addressed in the core. It might be very useful indeed.